# Can we say "taking too much car"?

Tags: expressions

Here is such a sentence on a workbook for middle-school students in China:

> Because they think taking too much car is bad for the environment.

I suspect the use of “taking too much car” here is Chinglish and would not be acceptable to native English speakers.

But another Chinese teacher said that the noun *car* here could be understood as an abstract noun, and therefore could be modified by *too much*.

So I wonder what you native speakers  think of the sentence. Do English-speaking people speak that way?

Comment: "taking too much car" is not idiomatic English. People just don't say that ever. In context the correct statement is most likely 'they think taking the car too much is bad...'.

Comment: It is actually possible to say "taking too much car" and have it make sense in English, but such an occasion would be hardly likely arise. For example, if you and I bought a car together and agreed to share its use equally, and then you began to use more than your share, I could accuse you of "taking too much car"—but that would be a metaphorical usage at best and even then it would sound odd (though fine for stylistic emphasis), and the more likely expressions would involve you *using* the car too much, etc. Speak those words with a foreign accent and people will assume an error.

Comment: By the way, that's a sentence fragment.

Comment: Note that _taking car_ may be the literal Chinese for driving/riding, so _much_ would make sense to them.

Comment: When I saw just the question, I thought that it was about an obese individual hogging the back seat. And even in that context, I wanted to add the word "up," as in "taking up too much car."

Comment: @SimonKuang: It is not, actually. The Chinese expression for driving a car is 开车 _kāichē_ (lit. ‘open car’), and the corresponding Chinese phrase, 开太多车 _kāi tài duō chē_ means ‘driving too many cars’, rather than ‘using the car too much’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Bad translation engine?

Comment: Quite possibly. Or just someone translating too literally (太多 _tài duō_ can mean ‘too much’ before mass nouns as well as ‘too many’ before countable nouns).

Comment: *Taking too much car* may not be idiomatic, but I like it anyway and I plan to add it to my idiolect. The phrase treats *car* as a mass noun, and English could definitely do with such a noun.

Comment: You can say "you're getting too much car for the what you paid" is perfectly fine, because the everything before after "car" helps clarify it as  a quantifiable noun. The workbook example, on the other hand, doesn't set such a context.

Answer (score 10):

You can say:

> I take too much coffee

and

> She takes too much time

However the expression: *take car* is really rare and as Mitch correctly pointed out it is not idiomatic. Native speakers would not normally say this. I fail to see how "car" could be interpreted as an abstract noun as one Chinese teacher suggested. You can however say

> Take **the** car out for a drive."

This is easily understood and does not sound odd at all.
*Taking too much the car out for a drive* sounds stilted; personally, I would never use it. If the speaker (or school text book in this case) wishes to communicate the opinion that the *frequency* in which cars are used is toxic for our health then something along the lines of

> Because they think **taking the car too often** is bad/harmful for the environment.

is I believe, more natural sounding.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think English supports this type of usage. In your context, *taking cars* sounds incorrect. Seems like a car is being taken from someone (as if the car is such a small/portable-by-hand object). Car being used as an abstract noun is uncommon. In fact, I have never come across any such usage.

In English, this sentence can be modified as:

> Because they think using too many cars is bad for the environment.

Comment: You can take the car downtown.

Comment: Yes, in your context, it sounds just perfect! I think I should modify my answer.

Comment: The problem is that things like “take the car” do not allow an adverb to be injected between them like that. One can take the car too much, but one cannot take too much the car.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that *too much* is equally happy to function as both an adjective  and an adverb, depending on placement.  When you say “take too much car”, it’s like “taking too much whiskey”: it becomes an adjective applying to the noun that follows it.

To make it an adverb, you have to move it to a place that adjectives don’t usually go, which leads to “taking the car too much”.

Answer (score 3):

I can say

> A Cadillac Escalade is too much car for me.

because it's too large, and has too many luxury features, so I'd rather drive a simpler car.

But when it comes to *taking the car*, I can't take a little bit of car or a lot of car. I can only drive exactly one car at a time, so I have to either take the car or not take a car at all.

As others have pointed out, the phrase you probably want is

> Taking the car too much is bad for the environment.